# Buying a domain in other country: larger response times?

Tags: seo, domains, web-hosting, optimization, load-time

I bought a domain in a very well know provider of domains in USA (Godaddy).

Now I want to use that domain for a site (local bussines) hosted in a server in Spain, and I'm wondering if I will get shorter response times if I have bought the domain in the same firm where I contract the hosting, or if search engines punish my site because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that holds the records for resolving domain to ip is generally cached on 100,000's of servers world wide, most ISP's cache this data as well as broadband routers can and even browsers. This is why name server changes take 1-72 hours generally to allow propagation (time for these servers to add your records.

So speed of your name servers are not an issue since they don't get this information from your site directly.

Answer (score 0):

> and I'm wondering if I will get shorter response times if I have
>   bought the domain in the same firm where I contract the hosting if
>   most of your potential visitors/customers are in Spain

As already said by Bybe it won't slow down your site, because domain DNS data are cached all over the WWW. Therefor most of your visitors' browsers will retrieve such data from the closer server, they won't need to ask Godaddy in US.
**But, beware** that if something happens to your server (downtime/crash) and the webhoster disappears (very common nowadays) or takes ages to solve the issue and you decide to move to another server, you will have to change the DNS entry at your domain. If your domain is not in Spain any change to its DNS will take much longer time to propagate to your Spain located visitors/customers compared to having the same domain in Spain.

---

> or if search engines punish my site because of that.

No, they won't at all! It could be the opposite, if you buy domain wherever, but place the server in US West (or even farer i.e. Singapore), since it's far away from Spain latency would slow down a bit your site, and search engine might *punish* you for this.